# Jquery $("#selector") returns empty data

Tags: jquery

I've a field in the form,trying to get this value using jquery.It is always returning null.

Where am i going wrong ?

Here is what i tried http://jsfiddle.net/9gJGM/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value parameter is shown in the alert, which you have left blank!

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="category" id="category" value="myValue"/>​
```

**JS**

```
var  productCategor =  $("#category").val();
           alert(productCategor);​
```

**EDIT**
In order to change the value of the textbox dynamically using JS, you can use the following.

```
$("#category").val("abcd");​
```

This works on my browsers. If you leave the value parameter empty, you are bound to get a blank returned on your alert.

**EDIT2**
This is the right way to do it.

```
<input type="text" name="category" id="category"/>
<input type="button" value="hit" onClick="hit();"/>

function hit(){
var  productCategor =  $("#category").val();
    alert(productCategor);
}
```

Comment: I'm giving the value in the text box then clicking run on jsfiddle

Comment: Which browser are you using? It should work with the value in it.

Comment: :Chrome,Firefox.Can you dynamically pass value to text box,insted of hard coding value and see whether it works,i get un defined.

Comment: $("#category").val("abcd");​ This changed the value to "abcd".

Comment: :Type the value in text box then see whether you get in jquery alert.

Comment: Ohkay. Now I see your issue. When you type it in, you get a blank. That is because when the event fires next time, the page has been reloaded and value is lost. So, you must associate the val() statement with a javascript event, or add a submit button.

Comment: Just did. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Run this, you can see it's selecting correctly:

```
var  productCategor =  $("#category").attr("id");
alert(productCategor);​
```

See this updated JS Fiddle to verify that you can enter text:

http://jsfiddle.net/7sH8f/1/

Comment: I'm giving the value in the text box then clicking run on jsfiddle

Comment: @user1415759 but when you click *Run*, it refreshes the page, so whatever you typed gets cleared.  To test this you'd need to display the value after a click event or something like that.

Comment: @user1415759 see here for an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/7sH8f/1/

Comment: :Without using onclick or any other event,it won 't post.Can you please upvote my question.

Answer (score 1):

Becuase your value is `empty`

```
<input type="text" name="category" id="category" value=""/>​
```

try put some data inside

```
<input type="text" name="category" id="category" value="MyVal"/>​
```

Comment: :I'm giving the value in the text box then clicking run on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gJGM/3/)

I added a value to the input just for the sake of seeing it working. In your case it was empty, there couldn't be shown any value.

Comment: :I'm giving the value in the text box then clicking run on jsfiddle.

Comment: @user1415759 ok, but jsfiddle resets all the values when you click Run.